# R Model Selection based on prediction accuracy

Tags: r

I am trying to decide which explanatory variables to use in my linear regression. My question is is there a package/function on R that:

Takes as inputs:

1. all the variables I think may effect the dependent variable
2. A Training Data set and a Test Data set

and then outputs the model (i.e. choice of the explanatory variables) that predicts the Test Data best using the Training Data (using some specified criteria to measure prediction accuracy)?

I can't find such a package/function but I feel there surely must be one?

Thanks

Comment: You can try this blog, you have the methodology and R code there: http://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/collinearity-and-stepwise-vif-selection/

Comment: Hi, that blog talks about other ways of model selection, but not ones based on predictive power